# Noob DIY Bluetooth Soldering Question

Tags: bluetooth, transmitter, receiver

I need your help to convert my earphone with boom mic to Bluetooth using this transmitter receiver. The problem I am facing is that once connected this device does not use the boom mic rather built in mic which I highlighted in third image.

What I want from you guys to guide me how can I remove the mic on the PCB and use the boom mic instead. What should be the connections? What I have learned from my research is that the Audio jack is PJ-320 which already support mic at 4th pole. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

[image: Earphone and Bluetooth Device]

[image: Front of Bluetooth device PCB]

[image: Back of Bluetooth device PCB]

Comment: In your pic of the top side of the PCB, looking at the 3.5mm TRRS socket, does the bottom-left pin, closest to the edge of the board & right next to that hole through the PCB, connect to a trace leading anywhere else on the board, or is it unconnected?

Comment: Hi thanks for your interest. unless the circuit is printer under audio jack and leading somewhere I am sure that that terminal is not connected to any thing.

Comment: If that pin is unconnected, then this device you have doesn't support external microphones; that pin is the microphone contact.

Comment: thanks for your comments appreciated. Is it possible to remove the built in mic and connect its terminal to the Audio Jack mic pin? Will that work? I am willing to just rip that built-in mic off if running a wire from mic terminal to audio jack works.